# Styling Contiguously Selected Table Cells

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, css

I have a table with selectable cells (via jQuery-UI selectable). Cells are selected individually, via cmd/ctrl-clicking, and via lasso. Selected cells get the "ui-selected" class. I style the selection by adding a 1 pixel thick orange border to that class. This looks silly when contiguous cells are selected. Please see this fiddle to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/derekprior/UxwD4/

What I'd like to do is draw the orange border only on sides where the neighboring cell is not also selected. By neighboring I mean both in the same row and in the row above and below. The result should be a single outline around the entre contiguous selection.

Can this be done with pure CSS? CSS3 selectors are fair game provided they are supported well enough in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari. If not, how about Javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/UxwD4/14/

```
$(function(){

    $("tbody").selectable({
        filter: 'td:not(.user)',
        stop: doIt
    });

    var cssClass = "ui-selected";
    var withBorder = "1px solid #F39814";
    var noBorder = "1px solid #dddddd";

    function doIt(){        
        $("td").css("border", noBorder);

        $("td." + cssClass).each(function(){
            var $this = $(this);
            var col = $this.index();

            $this.css("border", withBorder);

            if($this.prev().hasClass(cssClass)){
                 $this.css("border-left", noBorder);
            }

            if($this.next().hasClass(cssClass)){
                 $this.css("border-right", noBorder);
            }

            if($this.parent()
                   .prev()
                   .children().eq(col)
                   .hasClass(cssClass)){

                    $this.css("border-top", noBorder);
            }

            if($this.parent()
                   .next()
                   .children().eq(col)
                   .hasClass(cssClass)){

                    $this.css("border-bottom", noBorder);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: This seems to meet all requirements as best I can tell. It was the working code for the pseudo code I had in my head but didn't know the API for. I was hoping that there would be a way to do this with more css and less JS, but it looks like this is the best solution. Thanks!

Comment: There's a little "jump" when you make the first selection, *all* the borders seem to grow...

Comment: @wesley yeah, that's just because the default style applied by jquery-ui was only putting a border on the bottom and right.  Easy to fix by either adjusting the jquery to do the same http://jsfiddle.net/UxwD4/12/ or by defaulting the style to have all 4 borders http://jsfiddle.net/UxwD4/13/ or even with adding and removing classes instead of direct css manipulation.  There are other minor cleanup issues as well, was more just going for the functionality.

Comment: The table styling defaults were actually loaded in by Twitter Bootstrap. I think @luckykind addressed the border issues and moving more of the logic into CSS.

Comment: Turns out that this should use the stop handler rather than the selected handler. When using selected, you are unable to deselect previously selected cells while holding cmd. Moving this to the stopped event seems to fix that

Answer (score 1):

This can't be done with pure CSS (at least not without JavaScript manipulation), but with jQuery (since you're using the jQuery UI library already):

```
$('td').click(
    function(){
        if ($(this).prev('td').hasClass('ui-selected')){
            $(this).css('border-left-color','transparent');
            $(this).prev('td').css('border-right-color','transparent');
        }
        else if ($(this).next('td').hasClass('ui-selected')){
            $(this).css('border-right-color','transparent');
            $(this).next('td').css('border-left-color','transparent');
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/UxwD4/2/).

Comment: Thank you. However, this does not address the top and bottom borders when cells above/below are selcted. It also breaks down when selecting via lasso (click and drag) and if cells 1 and 3 are selected before selecting cell 2. I think the last gotchya can be fixed by changing the "else if" to an "if", but what about the other two?

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/LuckyKind/3pXyX/

A lot more CSS, a lot less jQuery

```
td {
    padding:1px
}

td.ui-selecting {
    background: #FECA40 !important;
}

td:not(.ui-selected) + .ui-selected {
    border-left: 1px solid #F39814 !important;
}

.ui-selected + td:not(.ui-selected) {
    border-left: 1px solid #F39814 !important;
}

tr.row-selected + tr.row-selected td.ui-selected {
    border-top: 1px solid #ddd !important;
}

tr:not(.row-selected) + tr.row-selected td.ui-selected {
    border-top: 1px solid #F39814 !important;
}

tbody > tr.row-selected:first-child td.ui-selected {
    border-top: 1px solid #F39814 !important;
}

tr.last-row-selected td.ui-selected {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #F39814 !important;
}
```

Then the jQuery...

```
$("tbody").selectable({
    filter: 'td:not(.user)',
    start: function(){
          $('tr.last-row-selected').removeClass('last-row-selected');        
    },
    stop: function(){
          $('td.ui-selected:last',this).parent().addClass('last-row-selected');        
          $('tr.row-selected',this).removeClass('row-selected');
          $('td.ui-selected',this).parent().addClass('row-selected');
    }
});
```

Comment: I like what you're thinking, but it doesn't work 100%. It has similar issues to @Rob's answer. For instance, select M,Tu,W for Sam and just Tu for Mallory - all in one selection. Sam is missing the bottom border on M and W.

Comment: ... or even simpler, select two non-contiguous cells in different rows. For example, Sam on Monday and Carl on Monday. Sam's selected cell should have a bottom border, but it does not.

Comment: shucks...

K... had to add a little bit more jQuery... but does the trick visually and cleaner code wise.

http://jsfiddle.net/LuckyKind/Cwm5U/

Comment: VERY nice! I can't decide which to use now. The only downside of your solution is that when doing multiple selections, the previously selected region disappears until you are done with the subsequent selection (due to the last line in the start function). Any way around that?

Comment: easily fixed by putting the last line from start into the beginning of stop! Comparing the jquery of my favorite solutions now.

Comment: Yep... I see what you mean... updated with your solution.

Twas a fun little challenge! ;)

Answer (score 1):

This can only be done using JavaScript. The `selected` event has to be used to detect the end of the selection. Then, check whether the previous/next row/cell has the `selected` class. If they do, add a class to deal with the relevant border.

Have a look at the code, I have used descriptive names.

**Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UxwD4/11/**
CSS:

```
.ui-border-top    { border-top: #eee; }
.ui-border-right  { border-right: #eee; }
.ui-border-bottom { border-bottom: #eee; }
.ui-border-left   { border-left: #eee; }
```

JavaScript:

```
$("tbody").selectable({
    filter: 'td:not(.user)',
    selected: function(){
        $('td.ui-selectee', this).each(function(){
            var cell = $(this),
                row = cell.parent(),
                cellIndex = cell.index();
            cell.removeClass('ui-border-top ui-border-right ui-border-bottom ui-border-left');
            if (cell.hasClass('ui-selected')) {
                var up = row.prev().children().eq(cellIndex).hasClass('ui-selected'),
                    right = cell.next().hasClass('ui-selected'),
                    down = row.next().children().eq(cellIndex).hasClass('ui-selected'),
                    left = cell.prev().hasClass('ui-selected');
                if (up) cell.addClass('ui-border-top');
                if (right) cell.addClass('ui-border-right');
                if (down) cell.addClass('ui-border-bottom');
                if (left) cell.addClass('ui-border-left');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: This is oh-so-close. For instance, select Sam on Monday, Mallory on Monday & Tuesday, and then Ethan on Thursday. The borders aren't quite right (at least in Chrome). I'm going to play with this some more.

Comment: See James' fiddle. It works 100%. I got three very helpful answers though - thanks a bunch.

Comment: @Derek `.children().eq()` has to be used instead of `.children()`. See my updated answer.

Comment: @Rob the issue here is your use of `.children(cellIndex)`.  Passing just a number is not valid.  You can change it to either `.children(":eq(...` or `.children().eq(...`